# What happens with excess items if my bag is full, and what should I do to avoid losing items?

Tags: pokemon-go

There's a default limit of 350 items in the bag (even though you can expand it through the shop). I am currently level 6 and have already ~250 items in my bag. I haven't done any battles yet, as all the gyms in my area are too strong for my pokémon at the moment. So I have a lot of Pokéballs, Heals and Revives that I don't need right now.

What happens once my bag is full? Will additional items go into a temporary overflow bag? Will I just lose them? Will they replace older items?

I'm afraid I will lose the valuable items gained through a level-up. Should I throw away items to avoid that? If so, what should I throw out first? Heals and Revives, as I don't need them right now? Or will they become too valuable later on and I should rather throw out some Pokéballs as those are the most common items to receive from a Pokéstop?

**TL;DR: What happens with items that exceed my bag size limit and what is the best strategy to avoid losing valuable items?**

Comment: If you're going to throw away your potions and revives to make more space, you may as well *try* the gyms. There's no downside to losing, you'll just need to revive and heal your pokemon.

Comment: They hop into your brain and start munching away at your peace of mind. "Maybe I could have stored something just a Little Bit Better".

Comment: just throw away revives.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are just under the limit(e.g. 349) and you activate a Pokestop you still get all the items from that stop.

If you're over the limit you won't get new items and only get 50xp.
If you level up when you're over the limit you still get all the items from that level up.

Since you're still level 6 you don't need to worry much, although if you're running out of Pokeballs you can throw some potions/revives away.

Comment: This answer is correct. However, I would add that even if you are over the item limit and you level up, you still get to keep all of your level-up bonus items. You just temporarily go over the limit.

Comment: It's in my answer, right after the 50xp bit.

Comment: I don't understand. I've got 397/350.  I've never seen a warning that my inventory is full, and i've definitely been getting at least the pokeballs from pokestops as i've run out of pokeballs.  so i'm tempted to dump some potions to ensure i do get the pokeballs from stops but it seems there's no point.

Comment: Update on this you don't get the xp anymore for trying to spin the pokestop and can't pick up any addition gifts which don't take up inventory spots.

Answer (score 10):

At Poké Stops: You will get a warning that your inventory is full and not receive any items when it's full.

At Level-Up: You will receive every item and it will show `380/350` to give an example.

The best strategy is to throw the revivers and heals aways in order that you always receive Pokeballs at Stops. Since you wrote that you don't participate in gyms anyway. Thus, Balls are most valuable for you.

Comment: dont like the idea of throwing away potions, throwing away revives should be good enough

Comment: @Gigala Depends on what you prefer at gym battling: Pushing gyms of own color or conquering other ones.

Answer (score 6):

From my experience of levelling, once you hit the 350 item limit:

Items gained from trainer level up WILL go into your bag, exceeding the limit. I've had 395/350 by doing this.

Using a Pokestop will gain no items, with the message "Your bag is full". You will still gain 50 exp from using the stop though.

At level 6, this isn't too much of an issue, from level 10 onwards though you may want to drop unused lower tier potions and Pokeballs to free space for Greatballs/Masterballs and Super Potions though.